# Laravel: translate validation messages in closure

Tags: laravel, validation, localization, closures

I'm using Laravel's HTTP Request Class to validate some form data. For some fields I needed a closure to make a custom validation.

Since my application has two localizations (english and german) I need to translate the error messages if the validation fails, which I already did.

The only problem I had was with the `$fail()`-message in the closure.

This is how I translate the message depending on the current localization within the closure:

```
if (app()->getLocale() == 'en') {
   $fail('Please choose a name for "' .$value. '" in order to continue.');
} 
elseif (app()->getLocale() == 'de') {
   $fail('Bitte wählen Sie einen Namen für "' .$value. '" um fortzufahren.');
}
```

I know I can use the `en.json`-file which I'm using for the translation of the whole site, but I wouldn't be able to use the `$value`inside of the sentence.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this?

**EDIT**

Since I'm using a closure I have to write the 'default' german error message inside the closure like this:

```
$fail('Bitte wählen Sie einen Namen für "' .$value. '" um fortzufahren.');
```

Doing it like this I get the value of the `$value` inside the error message that gets displayed in the view like this:

```
@if ($errors->has('person.*.name'))
   <label class="error-small">@lang($errors->first('person.*.name'))</label>
@endif
```

So the `$value` variable will be inserted in the message, so I can't access the variable anymore through the json translation file..

Answer (score 1):

And why can't you pass a parameter?

Take a look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/localization#replacing-parameters-in-translation-strings).

Something like this:

`messages.php`

```
'chose_name' => 'Please choose a name for :name in order to continue.'
```

```
__('messages.chose_name', ['name' => $value])
```

-- EDIT

For JSON

```
__('Please choose a name for :name in order to continue.', ['name' => $value])
```

Have you tried this:

`de.json`

```
{"Please choose a name for :name in order to continue.": "Bitte wählen Sie einen Namen für :name um fortzufahren."}
```

Comment: Is this possible to use in a json file, not in `messages.php`? I'm using translation strings, not short keys.

Comment: @ofmiceandmoon ofc, it is pretty much the same. Take a look at my edit.

Comment: how do I write it in the json file? Can I just put the sentence in there with the variable like this `:name` ?

Comment: @ofmiceandmoon take a look at my other edit, try it out and let me know.

Comment: You cannot pass a parameter in a text :) you will have to parse it somehow on the client side then which is bad.. put it in a `flash()` session maybe, which just lasts for one request.

Comment: So I might as well just leave it as it is now?

Comment: Yes, as long as you need to extract a value out of a text, you will have to do it another way.